# Annotate Plots in TikZ/PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following piece of code in my tex file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
ultra thick,
xshift=1.7in,
scale only axis,
width=1.2in,
height=1.25in,
xmin=2500, xmax=1000000,
ymin=1, ymax=1e7,
axis on top,
xlabel=Number of unknowns,
xlabel style={at={(0.125,-0.025)},anchor=south west},
ylabel=Time taken in seconds,
ylabel style={at={(0.22,0.125)},anchor=south west},
x tick label style={yshift=-3},
y tick label style={xshift=-2}]

\addplot [
color=red,
solid
]
coordinates{
(2500, 2)(10000, 6)(62500, 40)(250000, 155)(1000000, 600)
};

\addplot [
color=green,
solid
]
coordinates{
(2500, 52)(10000, 832)(62500, 32500)(250000, 520000)(1000000, 8320000)
};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I want to indicate on the figure that the red line is $10^4$ times faster than the green line by drawing an arrow between the two lines at the right extreme and writing $\times 10000$. How should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: A comment on your coding style, dont use `\tikzstyle` rather declare any styles within the `\begin{tikzpicture}[<here>]` or outside of the environment. (preferably using `\tikzset` which is consistent with `\pgfkeys`/`\pgfplotsset`).

Comment: I changed the tags and title of your question to make clear that you are using the ``pgfplots`` package and expanded your code to full ``MWE``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are more than one way of doing it but using the axis coordinate system seems the easiest for me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]    
\begin{loglogaxis}[
clip=false, %<---- Notice this option
ultra thick,
xshift=1.7in,
scale only axis,
width=1.2in,
height=1.25in,
xmin=2500, xmax=1000000,
ymin=1, ymax=1e7,
axis on top,
xlabel=Number of unknowns,
%xlabel style={at={(0.125,-0.025)},anchor=south west},
ylabel=Time taken in seconds,
%ylabel style={at={(0.22,0.125)},anchor=south west},
%x tick label style={yshift=-3},
%y tick label style={xshift=-2}
]

\addplot [color=red,solid]coordinates{(2500, 2)(10000, 6)(62500, 40)(250000, 155)(1000000, 600)};
\addplot [color=green,solid] coordinates{(2500, 52)(10000, 832)(62500, 32500)(250000, 520000)(1000000, 8320000)};
\draw[-latex,thick] (axis cs:2e6,1e3) -- (axis cs:2e6,1e7) node[right,midway] {$\times 10^4$};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @percusse. How do I move my arrow up or down as I want?

Comment: The arrow is following the axes for example `(axis cs:2e6,1e3)` is two million on `x` and a thousand on `y` if you change the `y` component the start point moves up and down. So in general, you change the coordinates.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to place coordinates at the ends of the two plots and use those to draw the arrow, so the arrow will depend directly on the data.

Instead of using `clip=false` to allow the arrow to be shown outside the axis, you can use the `after end axis/.code={...}` key to define the `\draw` command. This has the advantage that the plots will still be clipped (if you reduce `xmax`, for instance), but the arrow will still be shown.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    scale only axis,
    width=1.2in,
    height=1.25in,
    xmin=2500, xmax=1000000,
    ymin=1, ymax=1e7,
    axis on top,
    xlabel=Number of unknowns,
    ylabel=Time taken in seconds,
    after end axis/.code={
        \draw [-latex] (A) -- (B) node [right,midway] {$\times 10^4$};
    }
]

\addplot [red,solid]
    coordinates {(2500, 2)(10000, 6)(62500, 40)(250000, 155)(1000000, 600)}     
    coordinate [xshift=1em] (A);
\addplot [green,solid]
    coordinates {(2500, 52)(10000, 832)(62500, 32500)(250000, 520000)(1000000, 8320000)}
    coordinate [xshift=1em] (B);
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! How do I move my arrow up or down as I want?

Comment: @Marvis: Add a `yshift=<length>` to the two `coordinate` options in the `\addplot` command.

Comment: Ah, nice detail with the `after end axis`. I should keep that in mind.