# TikZ Plotting: Braces between tickmarks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is the best way to draw braces between tick marks?
It would be convenient to assign nodes at tick marks, is this doable?

The best method for placement that I have right now is a guess-and-check.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    xticklabels={}
    ]
\addplot [domain=-1:5] { -x * (x-4) };
\end{axis}
\draw [thick,decoration={brace,mirror},decorate] (1.2,3) -- (5.7,3) node[midway,below,yshift=-.1cm] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWEpicture]

Comment: Update: In my actual implementation (not the MWE), my brace fell out of the graphing area and was clipped off.

However, I did not want to use `clip=false`, since my graph would have extended out as well. To fix all this, I used `after end axis/.code={\draw [decoration={brace},decorate] (A) -- (B) node {yadda};` in the argument of `\begin{axis}`, and `\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:pi,0);`, `\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:5*pi/3,0);` just before `\end{axis}`.

I hope this helps anyone else who might run into the same situation!

Comment: (Special thanks to Jake's answer in [Annotate Plots in TikZ/PGFplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75202/annotate-plots-in-tikz-pgfplots).)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Below I present three levels of improvement:

1. You can move the `\draw` inside the `axis` environment and use the `axis cs` coordinate system which gives you access to the coordinates of the plot; also, you can use the `raise` option to shift the brace:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       axis x line = middle,
       axis y line = middle,
       xticklabels={}
       ]
   \addplot [domain=-1:5] { -x * (x-4) };
   \draw [thick,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] 
     (axis cs:0,0) --
       node[below=7pt] {4} 
     (axis cs:4,0);
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: output of solution 1]
2. You don't have to know beforehand the coordinates for the intersection points; you can let the `intersections` library do the calculations for you:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       axis x line = middle,
       axis y line = middle,
       xticklabels={},
       samples=100
       ]
   \addplot[name path=curve,domain=-1:5] { -x * (x-4) };
   \addplot[name path=line,domain=-1:5,forget plot] {0};
   \draw[
     name intersections={of=curve and line, by={a,b}},
     thick,
     decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate
   ] 
     (a) --
       node[below=7pt] {4} 
     (b);
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Finally you can also use the `calc` library and the `lengthconvert` package, for example, so the length (4) is also automatically calculated:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lengthconvert}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,calc}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[x=1cm,
       axis x line = middle,
       axis y line = middle,
       xticklabels={},
       samples=100
       ]
   \addplot[name path=curve,domain=-1:5] { -x * (x-4) };
   \addplot[name path=line,domain=-1:5,forget plot] {0};
   \draw[
     name intersections={of=curve and line, by={a,b}},
     decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},
     decorate
   ]
     let \p1 = ($ (a) - (b) $),
         \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
     in
     (a) --
       node[below=7pt] {\Convert[precision=1,number-only=true]{\n2}} 
     (b);
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```