# Not able to plot parabolas in an array

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following two `TikZ` environments should give similar displays.  I am trying to get five graphs of parabolas, each on the Cartesian plane, and to put a label of a.), b.), c.), d.), or e.) at the upper left corner of each graph - outside the `TikZ` environment.

The first display uses options in the axis environment, like naming the first plot `plot1` and moving the second plot with respect to the first plot with `at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)}`. Except for placing the labels a.), b.), c.), d.), and e.), it is the display that I want.  The second uses the `adjustbox` package. Each graph is too big and the parabolas on each Cartesian plane is artificially shifted. The graphs are displayed in the array that I want, and the labels a.), b.), c.), d.), or e.) seem to be positioned correctly, though.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is the left margin. \vskip1.25mm

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot1,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*x^(2)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)},anchor=west,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) + 3};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
  ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*(x^(2) - x)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot4,at={($(plot2.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*(x^(2) + x)};
  \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot5,at={($(plot3.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-6,ymax=6,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) - 0.5)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\vfill
\pagebreak


\noindent This is the left margin. \vskip1.25mm

a.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*x^(2)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
b.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) + 3};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
c.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*(x^(2) - x};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
d.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*(x^(2) + x)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
e.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) - 0.5};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the scale option for the tikzpicture environment to reduce the size of the plots.  I have not looked for the reason for the off positions graphs.  You need to check very carefully for missmatch in plotting area and the graph plotted .

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

a.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*x^(2)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
b.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) + 3};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
c.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*(x^(2) - x};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
d.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*(x^(2) + x)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
e.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,9) +(0,0.5) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-9) -- +(0,-0.5);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3,0) +(-0.5,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\begin{axis}[hide axis]\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) - 0.5};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an alternate way to display parabolas.  You only need to look at the pgfplots manual regarding options of the axis environment to see the other possibilities.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is the left margin. \vskip1.25mm

a.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{axis}[grid=none,
      mark = none, 
      xmin = -3, ymin = -45,
      xmax = 3,ymax = 45,
      axis lines*=middle,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      clip=false]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*x^(2)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
b.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{axis}[grid=none,
      mark = none, 
      xmin = -3, ymin = -45,
      xmax = 3,ymax = 45,
      axis lines*=middle,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      clip=false]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) + 3};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\par
c.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{axis}[grid=none,
      mark = none, 
      xmin = -3, ymin = -45,
      xmax = 3,ymax = 45,
      axis lines*=middle,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      clip=false]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*(x^(2) - x};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
d.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{axis}[grid=none,
      mark = none, 
      xmin = -3, ymin = -45,
      xmax = 3,ymax = 45,
      axis lines*=middle,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      clip=false]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*(x^(2) + x)};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\par
e.) \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
%These commands plot the second parabola on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{axis}[grid=none,
      mark = none, 
      xmin = -3, ymin = -45,
      xmax = 3,ymax = 45,
      axis lines*=middle,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      clip=false]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) - 0.5};\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Diagram using the first half of your code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is the left margin. \vskip1.25mm
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot1,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*x^(2)};
    \node at (axis cs:-4.5,14) [anchor= north west] {a.)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)},anchor=west,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) + 3};
    \node at (axis cs:-4.5,14) [anchor= north west] {b.)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
  ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*(x^(2) - x)};
    \node at (axis cs:-4.5,14) [anchor= north west] {c.)};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot4,at={($(plot2.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-9,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {5*(x^(2) + x)};
    \node at (axis cs:-4.5,14) [anchor= north west] {d.)};
  \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot5,at={($(plot3.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-6,ymax=6,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {-5*x^(2) - 0.5)};
    \node at (axis cs:-4.5,9) [anchor= north west] {e.)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The graphs that you displayed only use the adjustbox package.  As you commented, they are not displayed properly.  The only modification that you did was include [scale=.25]. Why does that horizontally shift the graphs?

Comment: Why are the parabolas in your display not centered across the y-axis?  You declare `domain=-3:3` in the `addplot` commands for them.

Comment: @user143462 I added a section with an alternate method of plotting parabolas.

Comment: Yes, I see your edits to the code using the `adjustbox` package - you plotted the parabolas with respect to the axis environment. (The second and third rows need to be shifted to the right a bit.)  May you suggest a web site explaining this package?

Comment: I would really like to know how to get the same display using the first code - the one in which I use the option  `at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)}`.  The only feature that I am missing is placing a.), ... and e.) to the left of the upper left corner of each graph.  Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user143462 I searched this site for "pgfplots text on graph" and from one of the hits I got a solution.   Documentation for adjustbox is at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf.  I recommend you bookmark http://texdoc.net/ and use this to find documentation for any LaTeX package contained in CTAN.

Comment: I have looked in `tex.stackexchange` for "pgfplots text on graph."  The web site suggested that I look at the following links: "Correctly align vertical text on a baseline in pgfplots,"  "Broken text on bottom of pgfplots,"  "Vertically center text on a page," and "Left & Right text on title."  (The last of these does not involve `TikZ` or `pgfplots`!)  May you provide me the link?

Comment: @user143462  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54088/annotating-a-pgfplots-graph  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75202/annotate-plots-in-tikz-pgfplots

Comment: To the first plot, I added `clip=false,` to the axis environment and `\node at (axis cs:-3,6.66) [anchor=east] {\bf{a.)}};' to the `TikZ` environment. To the second plot, I added `at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)},` to the axis environment. To the other environments, I added `at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1cm)$)},` (or `plot2.south` or `plot3.south) to their axis environments.  Now, it has the appearance that I wanted.